# SVG react component grabbing element by id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I have a SVG as a react component called `AdultDog`. My plan is to make all the tags in this react component that dont contain a certain number in the ID field disappear so that only tags with an id that contains a number are shown. i.e tags that have an ID 402 in it are shown. Ive tried to use `document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='402'])");` but this has two problems.

1. `document.querySelectorAll` grabs the whole html page not the `AdultDog` component, so how can i make it only select AdultDog?
2. with `document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='402'])");` it only selects ids called '402' but i want ids that have other words in it. i.e `402-tooth` and `402-recede`

```
import {ReactComponent as AdultDog} from '../../images/dog-dental-chart-with-treatments_v6.svg';

function DisplayTooth(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  console.log(props.toothnumber, 'Display tooth')

  useEffect(() => {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='tooth-402-GH-02'])");
    console.log('elements', elements)
  }, [props.toothnumber])


    return (<div>
        <div className='tooth-box'>
            <AdultDog></AdultDog>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    );
  }
  
  export default DisplayTooth;
```

This is quite a lot so any help would be appreciated! i cant find much documentation on SVGs as is.

Comment: IDs must start with a letter?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you'd be creating all the `<AdultDog>` components, e.g. `{dogs.map(dog => <AdultDogs key={dog.id} dog={dog}/>)}` and you could just add a filter e.g. `dogs.filter(your filter logic here).map()` to drop some of the dogs.

Another approach is to add a class to some elements so you can toggle it on/off.